# Using first sessions value in second sessions name

Tags: php, session, session-variables

Let's say we have

```
$_SESSION["number"]=1;
```

and

```
$_SESSION["color1"]='red';
```

What I want is to write something like

```
$_SESSION["color".$_SESSION["number"]]='red';
```

But unfortunately it cannot be done the way I'm trying. Any other way to do such trick ?

Comment: Does it give you an error or a notice?

Comment: Why you don't use array instead of indexing keys?

Comment: Yep, it's working. was my mistake, sorry. closing

Comment: Actually code that I was thinking is bad is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
$_SESSION["number"]=3;
$_SESSION["color1"]='red';

$_SESSION["color{$_SESSION["number"]}"]='red';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
$number = $_SESSION["number"];

$_SESSION["color".$number]='red';
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
$key = 'color'.$_SESSION['number'];
$_SESSION[$key] = 'red';
```

**Edit**
After checking, turns out your first guess also works as well.